# Access data in Power BI report using Rest API

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-rest-api

I am trying to get data in Power BI report using Power BI rest API. My intention is to take the data in the report and build a custom UI using Angular or React.

I am able to get report and dataset using the below APIs.
GET [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/{reportId}](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports/%7BreportId%7D)
GET [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/%7BdatasetId%7D)

I couldn't exactly find an API that gives me the data present in a report.
I have seen execute-queries but I though there must be an API that can get me the data by applying some filters also.
Please can you guide me?